# Potential energy given to an electron in a time-varying electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Given a general electric field $\epsilon(t) $ directed in the z direction, how would we calculate the potential energy given to an electron as a result of this field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if you want to apply this in a classical or quantum mehcanical context, but the application is similar in both cases. Given a [gauge choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory#Classical_electromagnetism), the electric and magnetic field are given by
$$\mathbf{E}(x,t)=-\nabla V(x,t)-\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}(x,t)}{\partial t};\\
\mathbf{B}(x,t)=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}(x,t),$$
and the classical equations of motion can be determined by the Lorentz force or via the [classical Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Charged_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field)
$$\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x},t)=\sum_i\frac{m\dot{x}_i^2}{2}+\sum_ie\dot{x}_iA_i(x,t)-eV(x,t)$$
Since, $\mathcal{L}=T-U$, and the kinectic energy is $T=\sum_i\dfrac{m\dot{x}_i^2}{2}$, we can associate the potential energy of the electron with
$$U(x,t)=-\sum_ie\dot{x}_iA_i(x,t)+eV(x,t)=-e\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)\cdot\mathbf{A}(x,t)+eV(x,t),$$
which is velocity dependent. The classical Hamiltonian is
$$H(x,p,t)=\sum_i\frac{\left(p_i-eA_i(x,t)\right)^2}{2m}+eV(x,t)$$
For the (non-relativistic) quantum mechanical context, we can use the above expression by changing the variables for operators (in position representation):
$$q_i\to Q_i=x_i\\
p_i\to P_i=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
to get the Hailtonian
$$H(t)=\sum_i\frac{\left(P_i-eA_i(Q_i,t)\right)^2}{2m}-eV(Q_i,t)$$
whose associated dynamics will be given by the Schrödinger equation
$$H(t)\psi(x,t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x,t), \qquad\psi(x,0)=\psi_0(x)$$
Be careful to realize that differently from the classical case, the operators $P_i$ and $A_i$ do not commute in general, i.e., $[P_i,A_i]\neq0$. Different gauge choices will yield to different potentials, bu the dynamics is not changed by this.